# Schelling's model of Segregation Python implementation with Geopandas

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, clustering, matplotlib

If you don't know what is Schelling's model of segregation, you can read it [here](http://nifty.stanford.edu/2014/mccown-schelling-model-segregation/).

> The Schelling model of segregation is an agent-based model that illustrates how individual tendencies regarding neighbors can lead to segregation. In the Schelling model, agents occupy cells of rectangular space. A cell can be occupied by a single agent only. Agents belong to one of two groups and are able to relocate according to the fraction of friends (i.e., agents of their own group) within a neighborhood around their location. The model's basic assumption is as follows: an agent, located in the center of a neighborhood where the fraction of friends f is less than a predefined tolerance threshold F (i.e., f < F), will try to relocate to a neighborhood for which the fraction of friends is at least f (i.e., f ≥ F)

I have written the following code to run the Schelling's model of segregation simulation.

```py
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shapely
import random
import itertools
import copy
import matplotlib.animation
import pandas as pd

class geo_schelling(object):

    def __init__(self,shapefile,spacing,empty_ratio,similarity_threshhold,n_iterations,ratio,races=2):
        self.shapefile=shapefile
        self.spacing=spacing
        self.empty_ratio=empty_ratio
        self.similarity_threshhold=similarity_threshhold
        self.n_iterations=n_iterations
        self.ratio=ratio
        self.races=races
        self.shape_cali=gp.read_file(shapefile)

    def generate_grid_in_polygon(self,spacing, polygon):

        ''' This Function generates evenly spaced points within the given 
            GeoDataFrame. The parameter 'spacing' defines the distance between 
            the points in coordinate units. '''

        # Get the bounds of the polygon
        minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds    
        # Now generate the entire grid
        x_coords = list(np.arange(np.floor(minx), int(np.ceil(maxx)), spacing))
        y_coords = list(np.arange(np.floor(miny), int(np.ceil(maxy)), spacing))
        grid = [Point(x) for x in zip(np.meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords)[0].flatten(), np.meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords)[1].flatten())]
        # Finally only keep the points within the polygon
        list_of_points = [point for point in grid if point.within(polygon)]
        return list(zip([point.x for point in list_of_points],[point.y for point in list_of_points]))

    def populate(self):
        self.all_counties=self.shape_cali.geometry
        self.empty_houses=[]
        self.agents={}
        self.all_houses=[]
        for county in self.all_counties:
            if type(county)==shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon:
                for j in county:
                    self.all_houses.extend(self.generate_grid_in_polygon(self.spacing,j))
            else:
                self.all_houses.extend(self.generate_grid_in_polygon(self.spacing,county))
        random.shuffle(self.all_houses)
        self.n_empty=int(self.empty_ratio*len(self.all_houses))
        self.empty_houses=self.all_houses[:self.n_empty]
        self.remaining_houses=self.all_houses[self.n_empty:]
        divider=int(round(len(self.remaining_houses)*self.ratio))
        houses_majority=self.remaining_houses[:divider]
        houses_minority=self.remaining_houses[divider:]
        self.agents.update(dict(zip(houses_majority,[1]*divider)))
        self.agents.update(dict(zip(houses_minority,[2]*int(len(self.remaining_houses)-divider))))
        return self.agents,self.empty_houses,len(self.all_houses)

    def plot(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
        agent_colors = {1:'b', 2:'r'}
        for agent,county in itertools.zip_longest(self.agents,self.all_counties):
            #ax.scatter(self.agent[0], self.agent[1], color=agent_colors[agents[agent]])
            if type(county)==shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon:
                for j in county:
                    x,y=j.exterior.xy
                    ax.plot(x,y)
            elif county is None:
                pass
            else:
                x,y=county.exterior.xy
                ax.plot(x,y)
            ax.scatter(agent[0], agent[1], color=agent_colors[self.agents[agent]])
        ax.set_title("Simulation", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

    def is_unsatisfied(self, x, y):

        """
        Checking if an agent is unsatisfied or satisified at its current
        position.
        """

        race = self.agents[(x,y)]
        count_similar = 0
        count_different = 0
        min_width=min(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,0])
        max_width=max(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,0])
        min_height=min(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,1])
        max_height=max(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,1])

        if x > min_width and y > min_height and (x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if y > min_height and (x,y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x,y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x,y-self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and y > min_height and (x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and (x-self.spacing,y) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x-self.spacing,y) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x-self.spacing,y)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and (x+self.spacing,y) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x+self.spacing,y) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1  
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
            if (x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass

        if (count_similar+count_different) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different) < self.similarity_threshhold

    def move_to_empty(self,x,y):
        race = self.agents[(x,y)]
        empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
        self.updated_agents[empty_house] = race
        del self.updated_agents[(x, y)]
        self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
        self.empty_houses.append((x, y))

    def update_animate(self):

        """
        Update the square on the basis of similarity threshhold. This is the 
        function which actually runs the simulation.
        """

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
        agent_colors = {1:'b', 2:'r'}
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        def update(i):
            self.old_agents = copy.deepcopy(self.agents)
            n_changes = 0
            for agent,county in itertools.zip_longest(self.old_agents,self.all_counties):
                #ax.scatter(self.agent[0], self.agent[1], color=agent_colors[agents[agent]])
                if type(county)==shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon:
                    for j in county:
                        x,y=j.exterior.xy
                        ax.plot(x,y)
                elif county is None:
                    pass
                else:
                    x,y=county.exterior.xy
                    ax.plot(x,y)
                ax.scatter(agent[0], agent[1], color=agent_colors[self.agents[agent]])
                ax.set_title('Simulation', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
                if self.is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
                    agent_race = self.agents[agent]
                    empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
                    self.agents[empty_house] = agent_race
                    del self.agents[agent]
                    self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
                    self.empty_houses.append(agent)
                    n_changes += 1
            if n_changes==0:
                return
        ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames= self.n_iterations,repeat=False)   
        plt.show()

    def update_normal(self):

        """
        This function is the normal version of the update and doesn't include 
        any animation whatsoever as it is in the case of the update_animate
        function.
        """

        for i in range(self.n_iterations):
            self.old_agents = copy.deepcopy(self.agents)
            n_changes = 0
            for agent in self.old_agents:
                if self.is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
                    agent_race = self.agents[agent]
                    empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
                    self.agents[empty_house] = agent_race
                    del self.agents[agent]
                    self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
                    self.empty_houses.append(agent)
                    n_changes += 1
            print(n_changes)
            print(i)
            if n_changes == 0:
                break    

    def calculate_similarity(self):

        """
        Checking if an agent is unsatisfied or satisified at its current
        position.
        """

        similarity = []
        min_width=min(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,0])
        max_width=max(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,0])
        min_height=min(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,1])
        max_height=max(np.array(self.all_houses)[:,1])

        for agent in self.agents:
            count_similar = 0
            count_different = 0
            x = agent[0]
            y = agent[1]
            race = self.agents[(x,y)]

            if x > min_width and y > min_height and (x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x-self.spacing, y-self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if y > min_height and (x,y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x,y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x,y-self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and y > min_height and (x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y-self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if x > min_width and (x-self.spacing,y) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x-self.spacing,y) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x-self.spacing,y)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and (x+self.spacing,y) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x+self.spacing,y) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if x > min_width and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x-self.spacing,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1  
                else:
                    pass
            if x > min_width and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass
            if x < (max_width-self.spacing) and y < (max_height-self.spacing) and (x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing) not in self.empty_houses:
                if (x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing) in self.agents:
                    if self.agents[(x+self.spacing,y+self.spacing)] == race:
                        count_similar += 1
                    else:
                        count_different += 1
                else:
                    pass

            if (count_similar+count_different) == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different) < self.similarity_threshhold

            try:
                similarity.append(float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different))
            except:
                similarity.append(1)
        return sum(similarity)/len(similarity)

    def get_data_by_county(self):

        """
        Return all the data by counties.
        """

        df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['County Name','Majority Population (Number)', 'Minority Population (Number)'])
        for county,name in zip(self.shape_cali.geometry,self.shape_cali.NAME):
            minority_num=0
            majority_num=0
            for agent in self.agents:
                if Point(agent).within(county):
                    if self.agents[agent]==1:
                        majority_num+=1
                    if self.agents[agent]==2:
                        minority_num+=1
            dic={'County Name':[name],'Majority Population (Number)':[majority_num],'Minority Population (Number)':[minority_num]}
            df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(dic),ignore_index=True)
        df['Total Population']=df['Majority Population (Number)']+df['Minority Population (Number)']
        df['Majority Population (%)']=df[['Total Population','Majority Population (Number)']].apply(lambda x:0 if x['Total Population']==0 else x['Majority Population (Number)']/x['Total Population'],axis=1)
        df['Minority Population (%)']=df[['Total Population','Minority Population (Number)']].apply(lambda x:0 if x['Total Population']==0 else x['Minority Population (Number)']/x['Total Population'],axis=1)
        return df

shapefile='CA.shp'
spacing=0.20
empty_ratio=0.30
similarity_threshhold=0.01
n_iterations=100
ratio=0.535
```

You can get the shapefile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12TpUiOTRxH2MmP6iVSH4mPRcg6aYsssK) if you want to try it. So the above implementation is fine but the runtime is very slow. I want to optimize the following methods `is_unsatisfied`,`generate_grid_in_polygon` . Is it possible to speed up these functions with numba or parallelization? Or any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I would suggest to add a small description of the problem statement that you linked also in the question directly.

Comment: @dfhwze I added a description. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to code review!
I've split my answer into three parts, each reviewing your code from a different perspective.

**Structural and Stylistic**

There is a coding style standard in python called PEP8. A good IDE like Pycharm will be able to tell you how to keep to it. It makes your code a lot more readable and consistent by using certain conventions which python coders will recognise. It helps with general organisation too.

You don't need to specify `else: pass`. This will be done automatically. Note this is *not* the same as `else: continue`.

You seem to have an indentation error in `check_similarity` with your `try: similarity.append(...` where the code is unreachable due to an early `return`. Again, using an IDE like pycharm will show these kinds of bugs straight away.

You regularly define instance attributes outside of your `__init__()`. This can be OK, but sometimes you then try to mutate these variables which can cause issues. (How can you change that which does not exist?) Defining all of your instance variables in your `__init__()` will likely let you know if you have some extra that you no longer need, or perhaps you have two doing the same thing. It's also easier to break up classes if that becomes necessary.

Perhaps the biggest issue with the code is the large blocks of `if else` in `is_unsatisfied()` and `check_similarity()`. This is basically unreadable with no comments as to what the conditions mean, lots of repeated checks and repeated code across the two methods. If you cleaned up these conditions I think you would find ways of exiting early to speed things up. For example, you perform the check `if x > min_width` 4 times, and `y < (max_height - self.spacing)` twice in the same method.

It's good that you've used docstrings but they're quite sparse and don't really help. `check_similarity()` for example says `"""Checking if an agent is unsatisfied or satisfied at its current position."""` However, you then loop over *all* agents in `self.agents` and your satisfied condition seems based on a single agent? Rewrite your docstrings and add comments!

I would split your class up - certainly into two classes, maybe three. All of the data gathering and plotting should be done separately to the core logic.

---

**Quick Tweaks**

- You can use tuple unpacking to define variables. e.g.

```py
# Old
x = agent[0]
y = agent[1]

# New
x, y = agent
```

Likewise, you can pass in unpacked tuples as arguments:

```py
# Old
if self.is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
    ...

# New
if self.is_unsatisfied(*agent):
    ...
```

- In python 3, classes don't need to specify that they inherit from `object`.
- It's clearer and more standard to say `if not x:` than `if x == 0:`
- If you have long lines, you can split them by going to a new line without closing a bracket. Very long lines are usually an indication of bad writing, though.
- Wrap your code to be executed in `if __name__ == '__main__':`
- Don't create instance attributes if they're only going to be used by a single method and never touched again. `self.old_agents` for example.
- You shouldn't need to `round()` and then cast to `int()`.
- `isinstance()` is the preferred way of checking types in python.
- Almost always, it's better to use `[]` and `{}` to cast to list or dict, rather than `list()` or `dict()`.
- Only use single letter variables when it makes sense. `x` and `y` is ok, `for j in county:` is not; what is `j`?
- Why are you looping over items, but using the item as an index?

```py
for agent in self.agents:
    if Point(agent).within(county):
        if self.agents[agent] == 1:
            ...
```

If you want to loop over an item and an index, use `enumerate()`.

---

**Speed**

You have used numpy, but only really to generate values. This isn't giving you any of its speed advantages. Where possible you want to perform vectorised operations on entire arrays, rather than looping over lists. For example, if you have some numpy array and want to check its values lie in a particular range:

```py
array = np.array([4, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1, 1, 5])

# Normal looping over array as list
return all(0 < item < 20 for item in array)

# Vectorised numpy operation
return (array > 0).all() and (array < 20).all()
```

If you clear up your code in `is_unsatisfied()` I think you'll be able to rewrite it to use these vectorised operations instead of what you currently have. I don't see any reason to use Numba or multithreading here.

You may find it too difficult to convert everything to numpy, in which case I would suggest using generators instead. In places where you're constantly appending to a list, or incrementing a value, you can switch to using `yield`. This allows you to create a generator expression, which will generally be faster.

You have two running counts for `count_similar` and `count_different`. I don't see why you can't just have a `count` which you increment and decrement. This means you don't need to get the average value at the end, and removes a lot of extra code.

---

There are lots of other changes which could be made but I think it might be better for you to implement the above, then post an updated question. You can then get more specific help with your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will make change in next couple of days and repost!

Comment: Hello, I have posted a new question with cleaned up code and also implemented most of the improvements suggested!