# Schelling's model of Segregation Python implementation with Geopandas (Follow-up)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, simulation, numba

This is the repost of the following [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225554/schellings-model-of-segregation-python-implementation-with-geopandas) as suggested by @HoboProber .

Again, if you don't know what is Schelling's model of segregation, you can read it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K3lT30gJWoKwu2jYvWR8HFcJKJzh6mdD?usp=sharing).

> The Schelling model of segregation is an agent-based model that illustrates how individual tendencies regarding neighbors can lead to segregation. In the Schelling model, agents occupy cells of rectangular space. A cell can be occupied by a single agent only. Agents belong to one of two groups and are able to relocate according to the fraction of friends (i.e., agents of their own group) within a neighborhood around their location. The model's basic assumption is as follows: an agent, located in the center of a neighborhood where the fraction of friends f is less than a predefined tolerance threshold F (i.e., f < F), will try to relocate to a neighborhood for which the fraction of friends is at least f (i.e., f ≥ F)

You can get the shapefile [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K3lT30gJWoKwu2jYvWR8HFcJKJzh6mdD?usp=sharing) if you want to try it.

I have implemented most of the changes suggested and also did split up my code in 4 different classes. Here is my complete code.

**geo_schelling_populate.py**

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd

class geo_schelling_populate:

    """ Generate the coordinates in a polygon (In this case a map of the state)
        on the basis of the given spacing and then randomly assign coordiantes 
        to different races and as empty houses. It also takes ratio and 
        empty_ratio in consideration. 

        Parameters
        ----------

            shapefile : str
                It is a string pointing to a geospatial vector data file which 
                has information for an american state's geometry data.

            spacing : float
                It defines the distance between the points in coordinate units.

            empty_ratio : float
                What percent of houses need to be kept empty.

            ratio : float
                What is the real ratio between the majority and minority in 
                reality in a given state.

            ratio : int
                Number of races. Currently the model is tested on 2 races, but 
                maybe in future support fot more races will be added.

        Attributes
        ----------

            shapefile : str
                Same as in parameter section

            spacing : float
                Same as in parameter section

            empty_ratio : float
                Same as in parameter section

            demographic_ratio : float
                Same as ratio in the parameter section

            races : int
                Same as in parameter section

            shape_file : geopandas.GeoDataFrame
                Pandas DataFrame with a geometry column generated from the .shp
                file

            df_allhouses : pandas.DataFrame
                Pandas DataFrame which contains all the different coordinates 
                generated inside a specific state.

            df_emptyhouses : pandas.DataFrame
                Pandas DataFrame which contains all the coordiantes which are 
                emptyhouses.

            df_agenthouses : pandas.DataFrame
                Pandas DataFrame which contains all the coordinates associated 
                with a race.

        Methods
        -------

            _generate_points()
                Private function! It generates the coordinates inside a given 
                shape. Returns a dataframe with all the coordiantes generated.

            populate()
                It populates the coordinates with either a race or denotes it 
                as an empty house. Returns a tuple with pandas dataframe of 
                empty houses and agent houses. Again agents are races in this 
                case.

    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        shapefile,
        spacing,
        empty_ratio,
        ratio,
        races=2,
        ):

        self.shapefile = shapefile
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.empty_ratio = empty_ratio
        self.demographic_ratio = ratio
        self.races = races
        self.shape_file = \
            gp.read_file(r"%s"%shapefile).explode().reset_index().drop(columns=['level_0'
                , 'level_1'])
        self.df_allhouses = pd.DataFrame([])
        self.df_emptyhouses = pd.DataFrame([])
        self.df_agenthouses = pd.DataFrame([])

    def _generate_points(self, polygon):
        """It returns a DataFrame with all the coordiantes inside a certain
           shape passed in as an parameter.

           Parameters
           ----------

               polygon : shapely.geometry.Polygon
                   A polygon object which contains the geometry of a county in 
                   a state.

          Returns
          -------

              A pandas DataFrame with all the coordiantes generated inside the 
              polygon object.
        """

        (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = polygon.bounds
        x_coords = np.arange(np.floor(minx), int(np.ceil(maxx)),
                             self.spacing)
        y_coords = np.arange(np.floor(miny), int(np.ceil(maxy)),
                             self.spacing)
        grid = np.column_stack((np.meshgrid(x_coords,
                               y_coords)[0].flatten(),
                               np.meshgrid(x_coords,
                               y_coords)[1].flatten()))
        df_points = pd.DataFrame.from_records(grid, columns=['X', 'Y'])
        df_points = df_points[df_points[['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda x: \
                              Point(x[0], x[1]).within(polygon),
                              axis=1)]
        return df_points.round(2)

    def populate(self):
        """ Populates the coordinates by assigning them a certain race or by 
            assigning them as empty houses.

            Parameters
            ----------
                No parameters

            Returns
            -------
                A tuple which consist two pandas DataFrames. One contains
                the coordiantes who have empty houses and the other contains
                the coordiante with a race assigned to them.
        """

        pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
        self.df_allhouses = \
            pd.concat(iter(self.shape_file.geometry.apply(lambda x: \
                      self._generate_points(x))), ignore_index=True)
        empty_ratio_seperator = round(self.empty_ratio
                * len(self.df_allhouses))
        self.df_allhouses['Agent/Empty'] = \
            np.random.permutation(np.asarray(['Empty']
                                  * empty_ratio_seperator
                                  + ['Agent'] * (len(self.df_allhouses)
                                  - empty_ratio_seperator)))
        self.df_emptyhouses = \
            self.df_allhouses[self.df_allhouses['Agent/Empty']
                              == 'Empty'][['X', 'Y'
                ]].reset_index(drop=True)
        self.df_agenthouses = \
            self.df_allhouses[self.df_allhouses['Agent/Empty']
                              == 'Agent'][['X', 'Y'
                ]].reset_index(drop=True)
        demographic_ratio_seperator = round(self.demographic_ratio
                * len(self.df_agenthouses))
        self.df_agenthouses['Race'] = \
            np.random.permutation(np.asarray([1]
                                  * demographic_ratio_seperator
                                  + [2] * (len(self.df_agenthouses)
                                  - demographic_ratio_seperator)))
        return (self.df_emptyhouses, self.df_agenthouses)
```

**geo_schelling_update.py**

```
import numpy as np
import math

class geo_schelling_update:

    """Updates the position of the races and the empty houses on the basis of 
       similarity threshold. Agents change positions if they have enough agents
       from their own races in a certain neighbourhood. In this scenario, 
       neighbourhood is defined as the eight nearest coordinate around the 
       coordinate we are checking satisfaction for.

       Parameters
       ----------

           n_iterations : int
               Maximum number of times, update method should run.

           spacing : float
               It defines the distance between the points in coordinate units.

           np_agenthouses : numpy array
               df_agenthouses converted to the numpy array for faster 
               computations.

           np_emptyhouses : numpy array
               df_emptyhouses converted to the numpy array for faster 
               computations.

           similarity_threshold : float
               What percent of similarity people want from their neighbours.

        Attributes
        ----------

            spacing : float
                Same as in parameter section

            n_iterations : int
                Same as in parameter section

            np_agenthouses : numpy array
                Same as in parameter section

            np_emptyhouses : numpy array
                Same as in parameter section

            similarity_threshold : float
                Same as in parameter section

        Methods
        -------

            _is_unsatisfied()
                Private function! It checks if an agent is satisfied or not at
                a certain position.

            _move_to_empty()
                Private function! Moves an unsatisified agent to a random empty
                house.

            _update_helper()
                Private functions! A helper function to help update method with 
                numpy's apply_along_axis method.

            update()
                It updates array as long as it reaches maximum number of 
                iterations or reaches a point where no  agent is unsatisfied.

        Getter
        ------

            get_agenthouses()
                Returns an array with all the agents at a certain coordinate.         
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        n_iterations,
        spacing,
        np_agenthouses,
        np_emptyhouses,
        similarity_threshold,
        ):

        self.spacing = spacing
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations
        self.np_emptyhouses = np_emptyhouses
        self.np_agenthouses = np_agenthouses
        self.similarity_threshold = similarity_threshold

    def _is_unsatisfied(self, x, y):
        """ Checks if an agent is unsatisfied at a certain position.

        Parameters
        ----------

            x : float
                x coordinate of the agent being checked

            y : float
                y coordinate of the agent being checked

        Returns
        -------
            True or False based on if the agent is satisfied or not.
        """

        race = np.extract(np.logical_and(np.equal(self.np_agenthouses[:
                          , 0], x), np.equal(self.np_agenthouses[:, 1],
                          y)), self.np_agenthouses[:, 2])[0]
        euclid_distance1 = round(math.hypot(self.spacing,
                                 self.spacing), 4)
        euclid_distance2 = self.spacing
        total_agents = \
            np.extract(np.logical_or(np.equal(np.round(np.hypot(self.np_agenthouses[:
                       , 0] - x, self.np_agenthouses[:, 1] - y), 4),
                       euclid_distance1),
                       np.equal(np.round(np.hypot(self.np_agenthouses[:
                       , 0] - x, self.np_agenthouses[:, 1] - y), 4),
                       euclid_distance2)), self.np_agenthouses[:, 2])
        if total_agents.size == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return total_agents[total_agents == race].size \
                / total_agents.size < self.similarity_threshold

    def _move_to_empty(self, x, y):
        """Moves the agent to a new position if the agent is unsatisfied.

          Parameters
          ----------

              x : float
                  x coordinate of the agent being checked

              y : float
                  y coordinate of the agent being checked

          Returns
          ------- 
              None
        """

        race = np.extract(np.logical_and(np.equal(self.np_agenthouses[:
                          , 0], x), np.equal(self.np_agenthouses[:, 1],
                          y)), self.np_agenthouses[:, 2])[0]
        (x_new, y_new) = \
            self.np_emptyhouses[np.random.choice(self.np_emptyhouses.shape[0],
                                1), :][0]
        self.np_agenthouses = \
            self.np_agenthouses[~np.logical_and(self.np_agenthouses[:,
                                0] == x, self.np_agenthouses[:, 1]
                                == y)]
        self.np_agenthouses = np.vstack([self.np_agenthouses, [x_new,
                y_new, race]])
        self.np_emptyhouses = \
            self.np_emptyhouses[~np.logical_and(self.np_emptyhouses[:,
                                0] == x_new, self.np_emptyhouses[:, 1]
                                == y_new)]
        self.np_emptyhouses = np.vstack([self.np_emptyhouses, [x, y]])

    def _update_helper(self, agent):
        """Helps the update function with number of changes made in every 
           iterations. 

           Parameters
           ----------

               agent : tuple
                   x and y coordinates for the agent's position.

           Returns
           -------

           1 if the position of the agent is changed, 0 if not.
        """

        if self._is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
            self._move_to_empty(agent[0], agent[1])
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def update(self):
        """Main player in updating the array with all the agents' position.
           It updates the array  until it reaches the iteration limit or the 
           number of changes become 0.

           Parameters
           ----------

               None

          Returns
          -------

              None
        """

        for i in np.arange(self.n_iterations):
            np_oldagenthouses = self.np_agenthouses.copy()
            n_changes = np.sum(np.apply_along_axis(self._update_helper,
                               1, np_oldagenthouses))
            print('n Changes---->' + str(n_changes))
            print(i)
            if n_changes == 0:
                break

    def get_agenthouses(self):
        return self.np_agenthouses
```

**geo_schelling_data.py**

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd

class geo_schelling_data:
    """Get the important data from the simulation required for the further 
       analysis. Following data is obtained:
               1) County Name
               2) Majority Population
               3) Minority Population
               4) Total Population
               5) Percentage of Majority Population
               6) Percentage of Minority Population

      Parameters
      ----------

          np_agenthouses : numpy array
              df_agenthouses converted to the numpy array for faster 
              computations.

          pd_shapefile : Pandas DataFrame
              Pandas DataFrame with a geometry column generated from the .shp
              file.

      Attributes
      ----------

          np_agenthouses : numpy array
              Same as in parameter section

          pd_shapefile : Pandas DataFrame
              Same as in parameter section

          df_county_data : Pandas DataFrame
              Pandas DataFrame with important data mentioned above.

     Methods
     -------

         _get_number_by_county()
             Private Function! It returns the number of majority and minority
             in a polygon.

        get_county_data()
            Returns the pandas DataFrame with the important data required for 
            the further analysis as mentioned above.
    """

    def __init__(self, np_agenthouses, pd_shapefile):
        self.np_agenthouses = np_agenthouses
        self.pd_shapefile = pd_shapefile
        self.df_county_data = pd.DataFrame([])

    def _get_number_by_county(self, geometry):
        """Returns the number of minority agents and majority agents within a 
           polygon. 

           Parameters
           ----------

               geometry : shapely.geometry.Polygon
                   A polygon object which contains the geometry of a county in 
                   a state.

           Returns
           -------

               A tuple with of minority agents and majority agents
        """

        num_majority = len([x[2] for x in list(self.np_agenthouses)
                           if Point(x[0], x[1]).within(geometry)
                           and x[2] == 1.0])
        num_minority = len([x[2] for x in list(self.np_agenthouses)
                           if Point(x[0], x[1]).within(geometry)
                           and x[2] == 2.0])
        return (num_majority, num_minority)

    def get_county_data(self):
        """Does calculation on Minority and Majority agents' number and returns
           a pandas dataframe for further analysis.

           Parameters
           ----------

               None

           Returns
           -------

               Pandas DataFrame

        """
        self.df_county_data['CountyName'] = self.pd_shapefile.NAMELSAD
        self.df_county_data['MajorityPop'] = \
            self.pd_shapefile.geometry.apply(lambda x: \
                self._get_number_by_county(x)[0])
        self.df_county_data['MinorityPop'] = \
            self.pd_shapefile.geometry.apply(lambda x: \
                self._get_number_by_county(x)[1])
        self.df_county_data['TotalPop'] = \
            self.df_county_data['MajorityPop'] \
            + self.df_county_data['MinorityPop']
        self.df_county_data['MajorityPopPercent'] = \
            self.df_county_data[['TotalPop', 'MajorityPop'
                                ]].apply(lambda x: (0 if x['TotalPop']
                == 0 else x['MajorityPop'] / x['TotalPop']), axis=1)
        self.df_county_data['MinorityPopPercent'] = \
            self.df_county_data[['TotalPop', 'MinorityPop'
                                ]].apply(lambda x: (0 if x['TotalPop']
                == 0 else x['MinorityPop'] / x['TotalPop']), axis=1)
        return self.df_county_data
```

**geo_schelling_plot.py**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

class geo_schelling_plot:
    """Visualize the simulation as it helps us interpret and analyze the 
       results. 

       Parameters
       ----------

           np_agenthouses : numpy array
                  df_agenthouses converted to the numpy array for faster 
                  computations.

           pd_shapefile : Pandas Series
                  Pandas Series of the geometry column generated from the .shp
                  file.

      Attributes
      ----------

          np_agenthouses : numpy array
              Same as in parameter section

          pd_shapefile : Pandas Series
              Same as in parameter section

      Methods
      -------

          plot()
              Plots the agents and shape on the same graph.

    """

    def __init__(self, np_agenthouses, pd_geometry):
        self.np_agenthouses = np_agenthouses
        self.pd_geometry = pd_geometry

    def plot(self):
        """Plots the agents and shape on the same graph so that one can see
           where the different agents lies. It is very helpful in the case when 
           the simulation is finished and you can see the changes occured in 
           the plot.

           Yellow is majority
           Violet is minority

           Parameters
           ----------

               None

           Returns
           -------

               None
        """

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
        self.pd_geometry.plot(ax=ax, color='white', edgecolor='black',linewidth=4)
        ax.scatter(self.np_agenthouses[:, 0], self.np_agenthouses[:,
                   1], c=self.np_agenthouses[:, 2])
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
```

**run.py**

```
from geo_optimized.geo_schelling_data import geo_schelling_data
from geo_optimized.geo_schelling_plot import geo_schelling_plot
from geo_optimized.geo_schelling_populate import geo_schelling_populate
from geo_optimized.geo_schelling_update import geo_schelling_update

shapefile = "Path to the shapefile"
spacing = 0.05
empty_ratio = 0.2
similarity_threshhold = 0.65
n_iterations = 100
ratio = 0.41

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schelling_populate = geo_schelling_populate(shapefile,
                                       spacing,
                                       empty_ratio,
                                       ratio)
    df_emptyhouses, df_agenthouses = schelling_populate.populate()
    np_agenthouses = df_agenthouses.to_numpy()
    np_emptyhouses = df_emptyhouses.to_numpy()
    pd_geometry = schelling_populate.shape_file.geometry
    schelling_update = geo_schelling_update(n_iterations,
                                     spacing,
                                     np_agenthouses,
                                     np_emptyhouses,similarity_threshhold)
    schelling_update.update()
    np_agenthouses = schelling_update.get_agenthouses()
    pd_shapefile = schelling_populate.shape_file
    schelling_plot = geo_schelling_plot(np_agenthouses,pd_geometry)
    schelling_plot.plot()
    schelling_get_data = geo_schelling_data(np_agenthouses,pd_shapefile)
    df_county_data = schelling_get_data.get_county_data()
```

I got rid of most of the `for` loops and replace the code with pandas and numpy to do some faster looping and also some vectorize operations. 
I believe this code is much more cleaner and faster than the previous one but still some improvements in speed and documentation can be made.

I believe I can still make some operations vectorize but don't know how to do it. If someone can suggest those that would be great. Also if someone can help me with the better documentation of the code, that would be great too. Currently I am using numpy style docstrings.

Also if someone can help me optimize my code with `numba` to achieve C level speed that would be great. I believe that geo_schelling_update.py can be speed up with numba but I am unable to do so.

Comment: I can't find the shapefile on the link you posted

Comment: @MaartenFabré Please try now!

Comment: that is only the `.shp`. There are some associated files which are needed https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262509

Comment: Try now please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code style

Try to use an IDE which integrates with linters (Pycodestyle, Pylama, Mypy,...). This alone found some 97 warning, ranging from no whitespaces after a comma, trailing whitespace, redundant backslashes, closing brackets not matching the indentation,...

All of these are no big issues, but they make the code look messy, and are easy to fix. I use a code formatter ([black](https://github.com/psf/black), but there is also yapf) with a maximum line length of 79 to take care of these smaller issues for me

Classes [should](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) be in `CapWords`

The `np_` prefix in some variable names is not helpful

## Python is not JAVA

Not everything needs to be in a class, and not every class needs to be in a separate file.

## pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

This is a sign that you are doing something dangerous with views or copies, and data might be lost when you change a subset. It is better to use `.loc` then to make sure you get a copy, and not a view

## ratio

You have 2 ratio's, so better call the second `demographic_ratio` or something

## keyword-only arguments

Methods with a lot of arguments can cause confusion, and are called with the wrong order from time to time. To prevent this, use keyword-only arguments if there are a lot, especially if they are of the same type, so the code does not trow an error immediately, but just gives a garbage answer

## occupation

`df_allhouses["Agent/Empty"]` lists whether a property is occupied. Since this is simply a flag, you can use 0 and 1 of `True` and `False` instead of `"Empty"` or `"Agent"` This will simplify a lot of the further processing. There is also no need to make this a column in `df_allhouses`.

I would also extract the method to provide this random population to a separate method:

```
def random_population(size, ratio):
    samples = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.bool)
    samples[: round(size * ratio)] = 1
    return np.random.permutation(samples)
```

So the houses that are ocupied are defined by `occupied = random_population(size=len(all_houses), ratio=1 - empty_ratio)`

## architecture

What `geo_schelling_populate` does is provide an empty simulation, that you later populate. You never do anything else with this object, apart from getting the shapefile. A more logic architecture would be a method to read the shapefile, and another method to deliver a populated simulation. No need for the class, and no need for the extra file

This is an interesting talk: [Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)  by Jack Diederich

I will convert the example of the populate here, but the same way of working can be done for the other parts. No need for a class, with just an `__init__` that populates the object variables, and then 1 action method that uses those object variables. It is better to just pass those as argument to a function

There is still a lot of other stuff to improve, especially on vectorisation, but I don't have time for that at this moment

---

```
from pathlib import Path

import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point


def _generate_points(polygon, spacing):
    """It returns a DataFrame with all the coordiantes inside a certain
        shape passed in as an parameter.

        Parameters
        ----------

            polygon : shapely.geometry.Polygon
                A polygon object which contains the geometry of a county in
                a state.

        Returns
        -------

            A pandas DataFrame with all the coordiantes generated inside the
            polygon object.
    """

    (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = polygon.bounds
    x_coords = np.arange(np.floor(minx), int(np.ceil(maxx)), spacing)
    y_coords = np.arange(np.floor(miny), int(np.ceil(maxy)), spacing)
    grid = np.column_stack(
        (
            np.meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords)[0].flatten(),
            np.meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords)[1].flatten(),
        )
    )
    df_points = pd.DataFrame.from_records(grid, columns=["X", "Y"])
    df_points = df_points[
        df_points[["X", "Y"]].apply(
            lambda x: Point(x[0], x[1]).within(polygon), axis=1
        )
    ]
    return df_points.round(2)


def random_population(size, ratio):
    samples = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.bool)
    samples[: round(size * ratio)] = 1
    return np.random.permutation(samples)


def populate_simulation(
    *,
    shape_file: gp.GeoDataFrame,
    spacing: float,
    empty_ratio: float,
    demographic_ratio: float,
    races=2
):
    """provides a random populated simulation

    ...

    """
    all_houses = pd.concat(
        iter(
            shape_file.geometry.apply(lambda x: _generate_points(x, spacing))
        ),
        ignore_index=True,
    )
    occupied = random_population(size=len(all_houses), ratio=1 - empty_ratio)

    agent_houses = all_houses.loc[occupied, ["X", "Y"]].reset_index(drop=True)
    empty_houses = all_houses.loc[~occupied, ["X", "Y"]].reset_index(drop=True)

    agent_houses["Race"] = random_population(
        len(agent_houses), demographic_ratio
    )
    # +1 if you need it to be 1 and 2
    return empty_houses, agent_houses


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shapefilename = Path(r"../../data/CA_Counties_TIGER.shp")
    shape_file = gp.read_file(shapefilename)  # no need

    spacing = 0.05
    empty_ratio = 0.2
    similarity_threshhold = 0.65
    n_iterations = 100
    demographic_ratio = 0.41
    empty_houses, agent_houses = populate_simulation(
        shape_file=shape_file,
        spacing=spacing,
        empty_ratio=empty_ratio,
        demographic_ratio=demographic_ratio,
        races=2,
    )

    ...
```

---

Part 2:

## random seed

When simulating, always give the possibility to give a random seed, so you can repeat the same simulation to verify certain results.

## Geopandas

You do a lot of distance calculations, and checks whether coordinates are withing Polygons semi-manually. It is a lot cleaner if you can let `GeoPandas` do that for you. If you keep the coordinates as `Point`s, instead of x and y columns:

```
def generate_points(polygon, spacing):
    (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = polygon.bounds
    x_coords = np.arange(np.floor(minx), (np.ceil(maxx)), spacing)
    y_coords = np.arange(np.floor(miny), (np.ceil(maxy)), spacing)
    grid_x, grid_y = map(np.ndarray.flatten, np.meshgrid(x_coords, y_coords))
    grid = gp.GeoSeries([Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(grid_x, grid_y)])
    return grid[grid.intersects(polygon)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

To get the houses in Los Angeles County:

> ```
> generate_points(shape_file.loc[5, "geometry"], .05).plot()
> ```

[image: Los Angeles County]

## grid creation

Best would be to extract the grid creation. This way you could in the future reuse the raw grid, with different simulation characteristics.

```
def create_grid(counties: gp.GeoSeries, spacing: float, random_seed=None):
    return gp.GeoDataFrame(
        pd.concat(
            {
                county.NAME: generate_points(county.geometry, spacing)
                for county in counties.itertuples()
            },
            names=["county"],
        )
        .rename("geometry")
        .reset_index(level="county")
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .astype({"county": "category"}),
        geometry="geometry",
    )
```

> ```
> all_houses = create_grid(counties=shape_file, spacing=spacing, random_seed=0)
> ```

```
def populate_simulation(
    *,
    all_houses,
    empty_ratio: float,
    demographic_ratio: float,
    races=2,
    random_seed=None,
):
    """provides a random populated simulation

    ...

    """

    if random_seed is not None:
        np.random.seed(random_seed)

    occupied = random_population(size=len(all_houses), ratio=1 - empty_ratio)
    race = random_population(size=int(occupied.sum()), ratio=demographic_ratio)

    agent_houses = gp.GeoDataFrame(
        {
            "race": race.astype(int),
            "county": all_houses.loc[occupied, "county"],
        },
        geometry=all_houses.loc[occupied, "geometry"].reset_index(drop=True),
    )
    empty_houses = all_houses[~occupied].reset_index(drop=True)
    return empty_houses, agent_houses
```

> ```
> empty_houses, agent_houses = populate_simulation(
>     all_houses=all_houses,
>     empty_ratio=.1,
>     demographic_ratio=.3,
>     races=2,
>     random_seed=0,
> )
> ```

The `agent_houses` then looks like this:

> ```
>     Race  geometry
> 0 0   POINT (-4 -9)
> 1 0   POINT (-3 -9)
> 2 0   POINT (-2 -9)
> 3 1   POINT (-1 -9)
> 4 0   POINT (0 -9)
> ```

To plot this:

> ```
>  agent_houses.plot(column="race", categorical=True, figsize=(10, 10))
> ```

[image: California population]

To check the neighbours who live within a perimeter of an agent is simple:

```
def get_neighbours(agent, agent_houses: gp.GeoDataFrame, spacing):
    """
    returns all the agents that live within  `perimeter` of the `agent`

    The `agent` excluding"""
    surroundings = agent.geometry.buffer(spacing * 1.5)  
    return agent_houses.loc[
        agent_houses.intersects(surroundings)
        & (agent_houses != agent).any(axis=1)
    ]
```

this can be tested:

```
agent = agent_houses.loc[4]
neighbours = get_neighbours(agent, agent_houses, radius=0.05 * 5)
neighbours
```

> ```
>   race    county  geometry
> 5     0   Sierra  POINT (-120.4500000000001 39.44999999999997)
> 17    1   Sierra  POINT (-120.5500000000001 39.49999999999997)
> 18    0   Sierra  POINT (-120.5000000000001 39.49999999999997)
> 19    0   Sierra  POINT (-120.4500000000001 39.49999999999997)
> 12321     0   Nevada  POINT (-120.5500000000001 39.39999999999998)
> 12322     0   Nevada  POINT (-120.5000000000001 39.39999999999998)
> 12323     0   Nevada  POINT (-120.4500000000001 39.39999999999998)
> 12334     0   Nevada  POINT (-120.5500000000001 39.44999999999997)
> ```

This is rather slow (500ms for a search among 15510 occupied houses)

Of you add x and y columns to a copy of the original:

```
agent_houses_b = agent_houses.assign(x=agent_houses.geometry.x, y=agent_houses.geometry.y)
```

and then use these column:

```
def get_neighbours3(agent, agent_houses: gp.GeoDataFrame, spacing):
    """
    returns all the agents that live within  `perimeter` of the `agent`

    The `agent` excluding"""
    close_x = (agent_houses.x - agent.geometry.x).abs() < spacing * 1.1
    close_y = (agent_houses.y - agent.geometry.y).abs() < spacing * 1.1
    return agent_houses.loc[
        (agent_houses.index != agent.name)  # skip the original agent
        & (close_x)
        & (close_y)
    ]
```

> ```
> get_neighbours3(agent, agent_houses_b, spacing)
> ```

returns in about 3ms

This will possibly go even faster of you do it per county, and use `DataFrame.groupby.transform` if the people on the border of one county don't count as neighbours for people of a neighbouring county

To find out who is satisfied:

```
satisfied_agents = pd.Series(
    {
        id_: is_satisfied(
            agent=agent,
            agent_houses=agent_houses_b,
            spacing=spacing,
            similarity_threshold=similarity_threshold,
        )
        for id_, agent in agent_houses.iterrows()
    },
    name="satisfied",
)
```

## value_counts

Checking whether an agent is satisfied becomes simple, just using `pd.Series.value_counts`

```
def is_satisfied(*, agent, agent_houses, spacing, similarity_threshold):
    neighbours = get_neighbours3(agent, agent_houses, spacing=spacing)
    if neighbours.empty:
        return False
    group_counts = neighbours["race"].value_counts()
    return group_counts.get(agent["race"], 0) / len(neighbours) < similarity_threshold
```

To get the count per race:

```
agent_houses.groupby(["race"])["geometry"].count().rename("count")
```

To get the count in a county:

```
agent_houses.groupby(["county", "race"])["geometry"].count().rename("count")
```

## update

One iteration in the update can then be described as:

```
def update(agent_houses, empty_houses, spacing, similarity_threshold):
    agent_houses_b = agent_houses.assign(
        x=agent_houses.geometry.x, y=agent_houses.geometry.y
    )
    satisfied_agents = pd.Series(
        {
            id_: is_satisfied(
                agent=agent,
                agent_houses=agent_houses_b,
                spacing=spacing,
                similarity_threshold=similarity_threshold,
            )
            for id_, agent in agent_houses.iterrows()
        },
        name="satisfied",
    )

    open_houses = pd.concat(
        (
            agent_houses.loc[~satisfied_agents, ["county", "geometry"]],
            empty_houses,
        ),
        ignore_index=True,
    )

    new_picks = np.random.choice(
        open_houses.index, size=(~satisfied_agents).sum(), replace=False
    )
    new_agent_houses = agent_houses.copy()
    new_agent_houses.loc[
        ~satisfied_agents, ["county", "geometry"]
    ] = open_houses.loc[new_picks]

    new_empty_houses = open_houses.drop(new_picks).reset_index(drop=True)

    return new_empty_houses, new_agent_houses
```

This redistributes all the empty houses and the houses of the people unsatisfied, simulating a instantaneous move of all the unsatisfied people

---

## **part 3**

## spatial datastructures.

There are some datastructures which are explicitly meant for spatial data, and finding nearest neighbours.

a [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) (or implemented in cython [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)) is specifically meant for stuff like this, and will speed up searches a lot when going to large grid.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree


grid_x = np.array([grid["geometry"].x, grid["geometry"].y, ]).T
tree = cKDTree(grid_xy)
```

To query:

```
tree.query_ball_point((-120.4, 35.7), spacing * 1.5)
```

This query only takes 70µs for those 17233 grid points, which is 30 times faster than `get_neighbours3`.

You can even look for all neighbour pairs with `tree.query_pairs(spacing * 1.5)`. This takes about as much time as 1 neighbour lookup in `neighbours3`

This means you can prepopulate a dict with all neighbours:

```
all_neighbours = defaultdict(list)

for i, j in tree.query_pairs(spacing * 1.5):
    all_neighbours[i].append(j)
    all_neighbours[j].append(i)
```

If you now keep the information on occupation and race in 2 separate numpy arrays, you can quickly look for all satisfied people:

```
occupied = random_population(size=len(grid), ratio=1 - empty_ratio)
race = random_population(size=int(occupied.sum()), ratio=demographic_ratio)


def is_satisfied2(agent, *, all_neighbours, occupied, race, similarity_index):
    if not occupied[agent] or agent not in all_neighbours:
        return False
    neighbours = all_neighbours[agent]
    neighbours_occupied = occupied[neighbours].sum()
    neighbours_same_race = (
        occupied[neighbours] & (race[neighbours] == race[agent])
    ).sum()
    return (neighbours_same_race / neighbours_occupied) > similarity_index
```

and all the satisfied people:

```
satisfied_agents = np.array(
    [
        is_satisfied2(
            agent,
            all_neighbours=all_neighbours,
            occupied=occupied,
            race=race,
            similarity_index=similarity_index,
        )
        for agent in np.arange(len(grid))
    ]
)
```

The people who want to move:

```
on_the_move = ~satisfied_agents & occupied
```

And the houses that are free is either `free_houses = ~satisfied_agents` or `free_houses = ~occupied` depending on your definition.

So update becomes as simple as:

```
def update(*, occupied, race, all_neighbours, similarity_index):
    satisfied_agents = np.array(
        [
            is_satisfied2(
                agent,
                all_neighbours=all_neighbours,
                occupied=occupied,
                race=race,
                similarity_index=similarity_index,
            )
            for agent in np.arange(len(grid))
        ]
    )
    on_the_move = ~satisfied_agents & occupied
    free_houses = ~satisfied_agents
    # or
    # free_houses = ~occupied

    assert len(on_the_move) <= len(free_houses) # they need a place to go

    new_houses = np.random.choice(
        free_houses, size=len(on_the_move), replace=False
    )

    new_occupied = occupied[:]
    new_occupied[on_the_move] = False
    new_occupied[new_houses] = True
    new_race = race[:]
    new_race[new_houses] = race[on_the_move]

    return new_occupied, new_race
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I really appreciate your answer. But ```np.random.binomial``` doesn't give me the exact number of 1s and 2s as I really need that

Comment: You are correct. I corrected my code

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me all the different ideas here. I will definitely implement them in my code and hopefully make it run faster and also make it cleaner but I think that one thing you didn't understand about the simulation is that the update method can't work the way you are trying it to work. When an agent is unsatisfied, it needed to be moved to an randomly chosen empty space right away because lets say if we get 5000 unsatisfied agents and only have 2000 empty houses,  where would be the other 3000 agents would go. An empty house need to be available all the time.

Comment: Which is why I decided the free houses as the ones not occupied by satisfied people, so a discontent person can move to a horse of another discontent

Comment: Also in your function populate_simulation, its not really populating Santa Barbara, LA and Ventura mainland

Answer (score 5):

### Documentation

The amount of documentation you've written is ambitious, but its arrangement is slightly unhelpful for a few reasons.

When documenting the "parameters to a class", you're really documenting the parameters to `__init__`. As such, this block:

```
    """
    Parameters
    ----------

        shapefile : str
            It is a string pointing to a geospatial vector data file which 
            has information for an american state's geometry data.

        spacing : float
            It defines the distance between the points in coordinate units.

        empty_ratio : float
            What percent of houses need to be kept empty.

        ratio : float
            What is the real ratio between the majority and minority in 
            reality in a given state.

        ratio : int
            Number of races. Currently the model is tested on 2 races, but 
            maybe in future support fot more races will be added.
    """
```

should be moved to the docstring of `__init__`.

Attributes generally aren't documented at all because they should mostly be private (prefixed with an underscore) and discouraged from public access except through functions. Regardless, such documentation should probably go into comments against the actual initialization of members in `__init__`.

Move the documentation for "Methods" to docstrings on each method.

### Typo

`coordiantes` = `coordinates`

Modern IDEs have spell checking support, such as PyCharm.

### Indentation

Perhaps moreso than in any other language, clear indentation in Python is critical. This:

```
    self.df_county_data['MinorityPopPercent'] = \
        self.df_county_data[['TotalPop', 'MinorityPop'
                            ]].apply(lambda x: (0 if x['TotalPop']
            == 0 else x['MinorityPop'] / x['TotalPop']), axis=1)
```

could be better represented like so:

```
self.df_county_data['MinorityPopPercent'] = (
    self.df_county_data[
        ['TotalPop', 'MinorityPop']
    ].apply(
        lambda x: (
            0 if x['TotalPop'] == 0 else x['MinorityPop'] / x['TotalPop']
        ),
        axis=1
    )
)
```

That being said, this is somewhat over-extending the usefulness of a lambda; you're probably better off just writing a function to pass to `apply`.